# Using a specified conditional VLOOKUP for values in a column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a list of SKU numbers, UPC codes, and dates. I am trying to get the UPC number and Last Use date for a specific SKU number. Since there are duplicates, I have created a sequence in column D that labels the number of times that SKU number appears.

[image: Table of Data I am working with.]

I am trying to fill columns using a VLOOKUP to specifically pull dates and UPCs for the sequence in column D. Is there a way to use a conditional statement, using a VLOOKUP to make this easier?

I tried using

```
=IF(["file name.xlsx]filename!$D:$D=1,VLOOKUP(lookup value, $A:$D,2,0),"")
```

I logically thought about it like this: If the value of a cell in column D = 1, then lookup the UPC or Date in columns B and C and print it in the column I desire.

[image: Table of Data that needs columns filled.]

In the image, column A is what I am starting with, but I need to fill in UPC1, LastUse1, etc. based on the sequence from the first image. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Worksheet function `UNIQUE` is an option to get unique sku code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, then either of these should work based on your excel versions, also it doesn't needs any helper/auxiliary columns.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$C$11,AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW($A$2:$A$11)-ROW($A$2)+1)/
($F2=$A$2:$A$11),INT((COLUMN(A1)-1)/2)+1),MOD(COLUMNS($A$1:A1)-1,2)+1),"")
```

---

The above formula needs to be filled down and filled right. Also note I have taken some of the data as an example, you may need to change the cell references or ranges accordingly as per your suit. And works with **`Excel 2010+`** onwards.

---

However if you are using **`MS365`** you could try this one as well.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F9</kbd>

```
=LET(u,UNIQUE(A2:A11),HSTACK(u,DROP(REDUCE("",u,LAMBDA(x,y,
        VSTACK(x,TOROW(FILTER(B2:C11,A2:A11=y))))),1)))
```

---

Comment: This one also worked for exactly what I needed! I wish I could post both of them as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The last number is the one of the column (so, in this case, the first)

```
=IF(F2=1,INDEX($C$2:$E$23,MATCH(C2,$C$2:$C$23,0),1))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! This one worked for what I needed!